# parentNode is null for tabs in bootstrap native?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-native

I'm a big fan of http://thednp.github.io/bootstrap.native/ which is a vanilla JS version of Bootstrap. Following their docs, I did this:

```
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item active">
      <a id="home-tab" class="nav-link" href="#home" data-toggle="tab" data-height="true" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true" role="tab">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
      <a id="profile-tab" class="nav-link" href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" data-height="true" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false" role="tab">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
      <a id="messages-tab" class="nav-link" href="#messages" data-toggle="tab" data-height="true" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false" role="tab">Messages</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
      <a id="settings-tab" class="nav-link" href="#settings" data-toggle="tab" data-height="true" aria-controls="settings" aria-selected="false" role="tab">Settings</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" aria-labelledby="home-tab" id="home">.1</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" aria-labelledby="profile-tab" id="profile">2</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" aria-labelledby="messages-tab" id="messages">3</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" aria-labelledby="settings-tab" id="settings">4</div>
  </div>
```

But when you click a tab, nothing happens. When this HTML is in the page, it also prints `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null` into the console.

When I try the JS approach by using `new Tab()` it also says that `Tab` is not defined.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: can you also show your js code please?

Comment: @ChrisLi no js code, it's using the data API. check the link to their docs for more info.